# Slider is not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Website slider is not working properly, when the screen resolution 1920 x 1200, slider image looks fine. when the screen resolution size like 1366 X 768 slider is cut left and right side, its not reduce automatically. is it any way we rectify this issue. website link is given below

http://www.newtonclients.com/testing/index6.html

Answer (score 0):

Some script is calculating the size of images in slider, and it isn't works well. I think it is probably based on window height, but should be just based on full width.

I think you should disable this script and just use `.img-responsive` Bootstrap class. Actually you can use Bootstrap carousel module, which is easier to implementation and for sure less bugy ;)

I will also improve this site experience, it looks very "heavy" and even scrolling cuts the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive, by default slider is moving it towards left by adding high value of `margin-left`. Which leads to your issue.

You can try fixing it by overwriting default css by your own. Add below snippet to your css file. And you can change the margin value and width as per your preference.

This will stretch image little bit. Hope this works.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
   .ms-slide .ms-slide-bgcont img{
      margin-left:-100px!important;
      width:126%!important;
      max-height:auto!important;
   }
}
```

Comment: i am done its not workable. when we zoom in its working.

Comment: May be your css is not on having proper priority. Try adding this at very bottom of your masterslider.css file. Check out this screenshot. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s334/sh/3ac14754-b9dc-4b93-a42a-75f3f566713b/2d3935cd321042de410e24075e9af4a1

Comment: hi some strange reason its not working. I am incorporated the code also. Problem is when 90% zoom in working, but 100% is croped left & right side.